# Existing database integration with Laravel 5.0

Tags: database, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I am new to laravel. I've got the whole database designed in phpmyadmin. Now I want to integrate the existing database in Laravel. Is there any way to do that? If so then do I have to create models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use your database in laravel but at first you have to provide your database credentials to allow the framework/Laravel to access your database. So, you can use a `.env` file or simply you can use the `config/database.php` to provide credentials, for example, to use your `mySql` database all you need to setup the database configuration as follows:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_database_name'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'your_database_username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_database_password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
```

Then regarding your second question, yes, you have to create models for each table or you can use `DB` facade to run queries directly from your controllers (not recommended). For example, to access your `posts` table you can create a `Post` model in `app` folder which may look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    // If your table name is other than posts
    // then use this property to tell Laravel
    // the table name.

    protected $table = 'posts';

}
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
$posts = \App\Post::all(); // Get all posts
$post = \App\Post::find(1); // Get the post with id 1
```

If you don't want to use Eloquent Model like one I've created above then you may use something like this:

```
$posts = \DB::table('posts')->get(); // Get allp posts
```

These are some basic examples to get you start. To learn more about the use cases of models/database you should visit [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2) and read the manual (find `Database` section and check [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I add my database credentials in database.php file, all the tables and relations will be recognised by laravel. All I have to do is create models for my tables?